# Alternative satellite and hybrid layers for Europe published on WMS

Tags: wms, layers

For an application I am building I require to show satellite (high resolution) and street view layers, preferably also a hybrid view. Unfortunately, due to the application not running on a typical GUI, restrictions of the Google Terms prohibit me from using Google Maps.

Looking for alternatives, I have had very little success in finding public WMS hosting alternative datasets. Hosting the data ourselves would require a redefinition of the project's scope which is, at this point, not an option.

Looking at questions asking for lists of WMS, I have unfortunately found many servers that are no longer online or providing the services I need. Do you know any WMS hosting the layers I need or, in case you don't, what WMS list would you consider most up to data and regularly maintained?

Comment: Can you describe the application and the area of interest in more detail? Have you looked at openstreetmap for the street layout?

Comment: We are building a tangible user interface for manipulating layers. If we can get hold of a WMS exposing the desired layer, we can usually integrate it without trouble. We are also already using OSM, namely terrestris for certain queries. While it gives a street layout, it does not provide street level satellite footage as provided by Google's StreetView which is what I would require.

Comment: What resolution do you consider high, and also could you work with output from WCS services?

Comment: A resolution where streets and houses are "clearly" visible. Also, using WCS would be possible as long as they can be addressed and parametrised by HTTP(S).